# How to check if ajax response contains specific value

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can you check to see whether the returned results contain a specific value?

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {

               //here i wanna check if the result return contains value "test"
               //i tried the following..
                 if($(result).contains("test")){
                 //do something but this doesn't seem to work ...
                 }

                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What is _"a specific value"_?

Comment: What is the format of the response? HTML? JSON? XML? Text? If text just use a string method `result.indexOf("test")`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if(result.indexOf("test") > -1)
```

---

Since this still gets up votes I'll edit in a more modern answer.

With es6 we can now use some more advanced array methods.

### [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

`result.includes("test")` which will return a true or false.

### [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If your array contains objects instead of string you can use

`result.some(r => r.name === 'test')` which will return true if an object in the array has the name test.

Comment: probably the right answer, but you won't get upvotes for quoting w3schools.  Try quoting MDN instead.

Comment: first answer i saw test and worked. Thanks Bud! 8 mins till i can accept.

Comment: @Alnitak What do you mean by w3schools what is the difference?

Comment: @Alnitak I linked w3 because it has the right information on the subject. If it didn't, I wouldn't.

Raju Kumar w3 is known for publishing bad information on some subjects. Just be careful when using them, try to find a 2nd opinion if you're not sure.

Comment: +1 for fixing your answer. Also agreed this w3schools link seems reasonable, though the issue people have is that by referencing them and directing traffic there you tend to validate it as a source, while it can often be not a good one. Be careful though — w3 !== w3schools. The former is the authority on all stuff web. The latter is a help website.

Comment: @RajuKumar w3schools is well known for having lots of incorrect information on it - see http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 12):

The jQuery object does not have a `contains` method. If you are expecting the returned result to be a string, you can check if your substring is contained within it:

```
if ( result.indexOf("test") > -1 ) {
    //do something
}
```

If your result is JSON, and you're checking for a top-level property, you can do:

```
if ( result.hasOwnProperty("test") ) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

:contains() is a selector. u can check it from here http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

for this example u can use indexOf like below